# Is there any reason to use Promise.all in a TypeORM transaction?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM to do two operations in one transaction. With no meaning to their order.
Will it actually be faster to use Promise.all, or do the commands queue up internally either way?

Basically, is there a difference in efficiency between the 2 options?

```js
// Option 1
getManager().transaction(async manager => {
  await Promise.all([
    manager.insert(...),
    manager.update(...),
  ]);
});;

// Option 2
getManager().transaction(async manager => {
  await manager.insert(...);
  await manager.update(...);
});
```

Just to clarify, I know that `Promise.all` can greatly improve performance in general in JavaScript due to single-threaded logic and event loop and whatnot.
I'm asking specifically about TypeORM and multiple queries in the same transactional manager, since they seem to run in order whether `Promise.all` is involved or not

Comment: Do you want your insert & update to run in parallel or not? This doesnt seem to have anything to do with typeorm AFAICS

Comment: If this is MySQL: Only 1 query can be executed on a single connection, and a transaction can only happen on a single connection. If you use transactions, you probably have to do things in sequence.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1014#issuecomment-336397434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeorm concurrent transactions with Promise.all can work incorrect because of Promise.all behavior *(doesn't wait all promise results).*

```
await Promise.all(tenDbTxns);

// 5/10 fulfilled
// 6 rejected ---> typeorm rollback 6/10
// 4/10 pending and after fulfilled will be committed to database
```

So as solutions you can use:

1. sequential query execution:

```
const data = [];
for (const tx of tenDbTxns) {
    const res = await tx;

    data.push(tx);
}
```

2. concurent execution but with Promise.allSettled *(waits all promise results)*:

```
const settled = await Promise.allSettled(tenDbTxns);
const data = [];
for (const res of settled) {
    if (res.status === 'rejected') {
        throw res.reason;
    }

    data.push(res.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM helps you by creating queries for you. If you are doing two things with DB, it will be two queries to the database in general. Let's say create a customer and create an invoice record. If you use promise all it will be quicker. But you have to make sure that you don't have any dependencies between requests.

Example: Invoices needs the customer previously created.

But if they are independent requests you can use promise all. Then you can check if every requests went okay, if they were, then you can commit the transaction, otherwise rollback.

I hope you find this useful, if you were asking for other thing, please provide more background so I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

TypeOrm doesn't work properly with promise.all and transactions (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1014). Yes it will be faster to do it with promise all, but transaction won't work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30559371)